# iOS App crashes when taking a photo

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, crash, uiimagepickercontroller

my App crashes when taking a photo due to a memory issue.

Now I tried to analyze my memory with instruments and actually I am using a maximum of 23 MB when the app crashes. I compared it with that Facebook App and it uses more than 70 MB so I do not have an idea why I am getting memory warnings...

I use the following code:

```
OverlayView *overlay = [[OverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:nil];
```

**Note:** I have tried it without the overlay view and it did not seem to change
**and** I tried it with and without animation.

BTW the app does not crash when presenting the imagepicker, but when the imagepicker is shown I receive multiple memory warnings.
The App crashes either when taking the photo or when hitting the 'use' button. Sometimes the App does not crash at all so I am very confused.

Maybe I need to do something in the didReceiveMemoryWarning method but I do not know what, maybe you can help me out with that!

Xcode shows this:

[image: memory issue]

**Update:**

This is what i get from the

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata =     {
    DPIHeight = 72;
    DPIWidth = 72;
    Orientation = 6;
    "{Exif}" =         {
        ApertureValue = "2.526068811667588";
        BrightnessValue = "3.440519128732857";
        ColorSpace = 1;
        DateTimeDigitized = "2013:09:26 14:33:48";
        DateTimeOriginal = "2013:09:26 14:33:48";
        ExposureMode = 0;
        ExposureProgram = 2;
        ExposureTime = "0.03333333333333333";
        FNumber = "2.4";
        Flash = 24;
        FocalLenIn35mmFilm = 35;
        FocalLength = "4.28";
        ISOSpeedRatings =             (
            50
        );
        LensMake = Apple;
        LensModel = "iPhone 4S back camera 4.28mm f/2.4";
        LensSpecification =             (
            "4.28",
            "4.28",
            "2.4",
            "2.4"
        );
        MeteringMode = 5;
        PixelXDimension = 3264;
        PixelYDimension = 2448;
        SceneType = 1;
        SensingMethod = 2;
        ShutterSpeedValue = "4.906905022631062";
        SubjectArea =             (
            1631,
            1223,
            881,
            881
        );
        SubsecTimeDigitized = 551;
        SubsecTimeOriginal = 551;
        WhiteBalance = 0;
    };
    "{MakerApple}" =         {
        1 = 0;
        3 =             {
            epoch = 0;
            flags = 1;
            timescale = 1000000000;
            value = 779858689639583;
        };
        4 = 0;
        5 = 128;
        6 = 138;
        7 = 0;
    };
    "{TIFF}" =         {
        DateTime = "2013:09:26 14:33:48";
        Make = Apple;
        Model = "iPhone 4S";
        Software = "7.0";
        XResolution = 72;
        YResolution = 72;
    };
};
UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage: 0x15668c60>";
```

}

Comment: Please post code from your `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` delegate method. This is probably what's causing the crash. My guess is you're trying to save the full size image, which is huge (~30 MB). Instead, you should be resizing this on a background thread, saving, and using resulting smaller image.

Comment: Error messages, crash message, backtrace?

Comment: @Zaph, there's enough information in the prompt- "app crashes when taking a photo due to a memory issue" is the issue; he's using `UIImagePickerController` per the provided code snippet; and `UIImagePickerController` is notorious for taking up a lot of memory.

Comment: @JRG-Developer I updated my question.
How do you resize the image in the background?

Comment: @YannickWin, checkout the answer provider. Give this a go. If you're still having problems after then, post your delegate method code, and I'll try to help more.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about the memory warning. If you're using `UIImagePickerController` on iPhone 4S or older devices, you'll typically get this warning, and you can't do much about it.

What's important is that you need to make sure you're resizing the image appropriately via your delegate method for `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`. If you try to save and use (such as displaying in `UIImageView`) the *original image*, you will crash on these older devices due to memory pressure.

See this [excellent blog post](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) for a discussion on the correct way to resize a `UIImage`.

Specifically, you will find this category to be helpful for resizing images correctly:

[UIImage+Resize.h](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/UIImage+Resize.h)

[UIImage+Resize.m](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/UIImage+Resize.m)

If you already use another method that works, great. Otherwise, this method works very well.

Using said category methods, here's an example of `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` using GCD to do the resizing on a background thread:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Dismiss the image picker first to free its memory
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if (!originalImage)
        return;

    // Optionally set a placeholder image here while resizing happens in background

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Set desired maximum height and calculate width
        CGFloat height = 640.0f;
        CGFloat width = (height / self.size.height) * self.size.width;

        UIImage * image = [originalImage resizedImage:CGSizeMake(width, height) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];

        // Save and use this image
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so can I use this method instead of this

`- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo`

...?

Comment: That method was deprecated in iOS 3.0, so I'd recommend using the newer method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` as shown above - see the Apple docs on it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:

Comment: It basically does the same thing, you just have to get the original image from the `info` dictionary... that's what `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]` in the code does... which is the same as writing `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]` (newer syntax)

Comment: Wait, I think I am getting to it. Shame on me I did not use your complete code. I tried your complete code now and on this line: `UIImage * image = [originalImage resizedImage:CGSizeMake(width, height) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];`  I am getting the Xcode error: No visible interface for UIImage declares the selector resizedImage:interpolationQuality

Comment: If you want to use this resize method (it's not part of `UIImage` by default), then you will need to download and add the provided `UIImage+Resize` category to your project. Also make sure you `#import` it, or put into your project precompiled header, `.pch` file.

Answer (score 0):

Iam also facing the same problem and i have found an patch to minimize the issue .So What i does is simply block the main thread untill image picker is dismissed. that's it .

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
__weak typeof(picker) wSelf = picker;
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 *NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

[wSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    @try {


        [self saveImage:info];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception:%@",exception);
    }
    @finally {
    }

}];});}

-(void)saveImage:(NSDictionary *)info{
 [KAppdelegate ShowLoader];

  UIImage *image=(UIImage *)[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

  ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
 dispatch_queue_t queue =  dispatch_queue_create("com.myApp.saveToCameraRoll", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){

    if (error) {
        // handle the error
    }
    else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // perhaps indicate to the user that save has finished

        });
    }

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);

}];

dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

});}
```